# for loop condition ignored

Tags: loops, for-loop, conditional-statements, infinite

I've just started learning Java a few days ago.
I was trying to create a method with two parameters that prints the products of the two numbers, until the product is less than or equal to 200.
For example: the inputs are 5.0 and 0.5. I want this operation: 5.0 * 0.5, print the result (2.5), then I want the update to be increased by 0.1, so from 0.5 to 0.6. Make the operation again 5.0 * 0.6, print the result, increase the update to 0.7 and so on, until the result of the operation n*n is <=200.
Just like this:
inputs: 5.0, 0.5
print:
2,5
3
3,5
...
200

I don't understand why the loop is infinite, I guess the condition is ignored. What is the problem?

Here are some variations on the code I wrote

```
void ration(double lbs, double increment) {
    for(double product=(lbs*increment); product <= 200.0; increment+=0.1){
            System.out.println(lbs*increment);
    }
}
```

this prints an infinite loop of the results between n*n (let's say 5 10 15 20 25..)

```
void ration(double lbs, double increment) {
    for(double product=(lbs*increment); product <= 200.0; increment+=0.1){
            System.out.println(product);
    }
}
```

This prints the first result of n * n forver... (let's say 5 5 5 5 5 5..)

What am I doing wrong? Any advice would be greately appreciated.
Thank you

Comment: When does `product` ever change in either loop?

Comment: I've just edited the main post, sorry. The product never seems to change.

Comment: And what variable are your `for` loop conditions based on?

Comment: the variable product. Thank you Andrew for your input, now the loop is not infinite anymore:
void ration(double lbs, double increment) {
    double product = 0;
    for(; product<=200; product=(lbs*increment), inc+=0.1) {
        System.out.println(product);
    }
}